# nginx returns 404 when I visit the URL without www

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

When visit: [www.fxmates.com/](http://www.fxmates.com/) => return 404

visit: https://fxmates.com/ => OK

Here's my Nginx config file:

[image]

What's wrong？

Comment: Please, add the nginx config file as file. Images are harder to manage in this context. And, the title of your question does not match the body.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code actually:

Firsty, in the line:
[image]

Make it:

> server_name fxmates.com www.fxmates.com;

Also, remove this line:

[image]
It's what causes your nginx webserver to give the user a 404 page each and everytime the user goes to any page on `fxmates.com` on `http://fxmates.com`, since in any browser when you type `fxmates.com` only without `https://` the browser defaults to `http://` and then the `return 404` block pushes `404` to the user's browser.

And the reason this doesn't effect you when you're directly typing `https://` in front because, `nginx` uses the above `server block` in the configuration file.

Hope it helps.